How come Gnome developers consider Ubuntu 22.04 too old to take up bug reports regarding it?
I got this message from a developer about the Ubuntu version:

Hi, thanks for reporting this. Unfortunately you are using a version
that is too old and not supported anymore by GNOME developers. There
will not be any bug fixes or feature additions by GNOME developers for
the version that you use. Please feel free to reopen this issue if
this situation still happens with a more recent version of GNOME. Feel
also free to report this in the issue tracking system of your Linux
distribution as your Linux distribution still supports your current
version.


GNOME developers (and many such upstreams) will only accept bug reports against the latest releases. To report bugs on released versions of Ubuntu, report them with Ubuntu instead, and let the Ubuntu devs decide if reporting upstream is worth it.

I tried with ALT+F2 and ubuntu-bug it informed me that I had to contact developer, after developer answer iI looked in foroum and found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

Don't forget Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is even old in Ubuntu terms, newer releases were Ubuntu 22.10 (now EOL), Ubuntu 23.04 (also EOL now) and the latest stable release being Ubuntu 23.10. You're trying to file a bug report from a release that is four releases now (with the next releases soon to reach RC or Release Candidate, ie. it'll soon be five releases ago).

To file bugs with Ubuntu, please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (ie. you'll be told to use ubuntu-bug package where package is the name of the package you're having issue with. Refer to link for places where you can get help too (eg. IRC, Matrix, etc)
